# How to load modal when page is loaded

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am using jquerymodal.com to load modal window, but I need load modal when the page is loaded, not with button click.

The code that I using is:

```
<script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#tour-virtual').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the on() method

```
<script>
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#tour-virtual').modal('show');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi SiriusLee! Thank you for your help, but this not working. I think I have bad "$('#tour-virtual').modal('show');" because of the way the plugin handles it.

Comment: Do you need to use the .load event? $(window).ready may solve this problem